# Laravel Livewire - Class "Facades\Livewire\GenerateSignedUploadUrl" not found

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-9, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament

**Unable to upload file in Laravel Filamentphp**

I used the following Filamentphp file upload component.

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\FileUpload;
 
FileUpload::make('bulk_upload')
    ->disk('local')
    ->directory('uploads')
```

The issue of

> "Class Facades\Livewire\GenerateSignedUploadUrl not found"

arises, when selecting a file.

I cleared my application cache and view using the following command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

1. Go to the "vendor/livewire/livewire/src/WithFileUploads.php" file.
2. I changed "use Livewire\GenerateSignedUploadUrl" instead of "use Facades\Livewire\GenerateSignedUploadUrl".
3. Go to the "vendor/livewire/livewire/src/GenerateSignedUploadUrl.php".

**Add static**

```
public static function forLocal()
   {
       return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
           'livewire.upload-file', now()->addMinutes(FileUploadConfiguration::maxUploadTime())
       );
   }
```

**Instead of**

```
 public function forLocal()
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'livewire.upload-file', now()->addMinutes(FileUploadConfiguration::maxUploadTime())
        );
    }
```